# Accessing Google Drive API from a Script Without Browser Redirection

Tags: ruby, google-api

I am developing a simple script (using Ruby and the google-api-client gem) for personal use that needs to download a file periodically from my Google Drive account. The script will then process the file and send me an email with the result. I understand that I need to use the Google Drive API in order to do this. I have registered my "application" in the Google Developer's Console, but am confused when it comes to accessing the data.

Google presents me with 3 options for my application type:

- Web Application (accessed by web browsers over a network)
- Service Account (calls Google APIs on behalf of your application)
- Installed Application (Runs on a desktop computer or handheld device)

My script will run as a cron job and should not require any user input. This makes me think that "Service Account" is the correct choice. But when I follow the link to learn more about "Service Accounts", the first sentence is "Google APIs such as the Prediction API and Google Cloud Storage can act on behalf of your application without accessing user information," suggesting this type is not appropriate for accessing protected information.

So: **how can I write a script that accesses private data from Google Drive periodically without requiring user input at access time**? I would think it is possible to just generate a key and embed this in the script, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Service account is going to be the one that you want. If you have a Google Apps account, you'll need to [delegate](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) access to your service account. If you don't, I have no idea about how to make the service account work with private data Apis.

Answer (score 0):

the SA needs domain wide delegation (DWD):
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

The problem is, DWD grants the SA unrestricted access to all the accounts of the google workspace of the domain.
I'm still searching a way to limit delegation to a single account.